# "Heap corruption detected" when using free()

Tags: c, free, calloc

I'm pretty new to C (it's actually my first assignment with pointers), and I cant figure out this bug...

here is my code:

```
void str_rv(char c[]) {
    int i, len = str_ln(c);
    char *rev = (char*)calloc(len, sizeof(char));

    check_mem(rev);

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        rev[i] = c[len - (i + 1)];
    }

    rev[len] = '\0';
    str_cpy(rev, c);

    printf("Current string is ");
    str_print(c);
    putchar('\n');
    free(rev);
}
```

In this function, I'm trying to reverse a string that I got from `sacnf()`.
when i debugged it, it ran fine, until the last line where I use `free()`. I read a bit online, and I'm sure it's the only place where I try to rfee this memory.

Help?

Comment: You're writing past your allocated bounds (you're allocating memory for `len` chars, so the last accessible index is `rev[len-1]` since rev starts at 0).

Comment: Use calloc(len+1, sizeof(char))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overwriting beyond the bounds of array here:

```
rev[len] = '\0';
```

You have allocated only `len` chars. Instead you can allocate `len +1` chars.

Thus causing *[undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*. This probably resulted the corruption of meta data which results in `free()`'s failure.

Also, [don't cast the return of `malloc()/calloc()` etc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html). You should also check whether `calloc()` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate len to that, the index starts from 0 to len - 1 
So you must allocate len +1 to it so you can use index len for NULL